# excel macro - checkbox to select other checkboxes

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

i'm trying to have a selection of optoins via checkboxes.  I want to have one specific box automatically check a few other boxes.  I'm getting `Object required (Error 424)` when i click the box in question after assigning the macro below:

any help would be much appreciated

```
Public Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox21.Value = True Then
    CheckBox2.Value = True
    CheckBox5.Value = True
    CheckBox6.Value = True
    CheckBox18.Value = True
    CheckBox19.Value = True
    CheckBox20.Value = True
    CheckBox22.Value = True
    CheckBox23.Value = True
    CheckBox2.Enabled = False
    CheckBox5.Enabled = False
    CheckBox6.Enabled = False
    CheckBox18.Enabled = False
    CheckBox19.Enabled = False
    CheckBox20.Enabled = False
    CheckBox22.Enabled = False
    CheckBox23.Enabled = False
Else
    CheckBox2.Enabled = True
    CheckBox5.Enabled = True
    CheckBox6.Enabled = True
    CheckBox18.Enabled = True
    CheckBox19.Enabled = True
    CheckBox20.Enabled = True
    CheckBox22.Enabled = True
    CheckBox23.Enabled = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What kind of checkbox did you use? Form Control or ActiveX? This error suggests that one or all of these checkboxes don't exist. If they are Form Control then this isn't how you would interact with them.

Comment: hi JNevill, i used form control checkboxes.  so i need to replace with activeX checkboxes? i used form control because i'm using the link to a cell with true/false in calculations elsewhere in the document

Comment: Yes, I would suggest if you are going to be utilizing VBA to interact with your excel form stuff, then go with ActiveX. Program-ability is 1000x easier. If you stick with Form Controls then consider changing the value of the linked cells via VBA for each checkbox to "true" or "false" instead of trying to set their `.value` property. When going to ActiveX then you can set a cell to true/false in VBA when the checkbox is clicked using it's click event. More overhead, but more control. There's definitely trade-offs in both routes.

Comment: can you expand on this " linked cells via VBA for each checkbox to "true" or "false" instead of trying to set their .value property" 
i use the true/false logic elsewhere to do some math but i thought i had to use the value in the macro.  can i reference the true/false linked cell in a macro?  would i just do something like this:
If D5 = True Then
    D6 = True

Comment: actually i figured it out 

Public Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If Range("AF3").Value = True Then
        Range("AA3").Value = True
        Range("AC3").Value = True
        Range("AE3").Value = True
        Range("AG3").Value = True
        Range("AD3").Value = True
        Range("AI3").Value = True
    Else
        Range("AA3").Value = False
        Range("AC3").Value = False
        Range("AE3").Value = False
        Range("AG3").Value = False
        Range("AD3").Value = False
        Range("AI3").Value = False
    End If
End Sub
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
Private Sub CheckBox21_Change()

If CheckBox21.Value = True Then
    CheckBox2.Value = True
    CheckBox5.Value = True
    CheckBox6.Value = True
    CheckBox18.Value = True
    CheckBox19.Value = True
Else
    CheckBox2.Value = False
    CheckBox5.Value = False
    CheckBox6.Value = False
    CheckBox18.Value = False
    CheckBox19.Value = False
End If
```

Comment: do i have to run as a private sub?  i have this built in one of the modules as a public sub.  is that just wrong?  i'm not sure how to assign a private sub to a checkbox.  i changed private to public in your example and added end sub at the bottom.  i still get the error and debug highlights that first IF line

Comment: In the IF line, there is a double ".Value.Value" which causes an error. You can also change the sub name from "CheckBox21_Change" to "CheckBox1_Change" like in your example (and rename your old one).
If that won't help, try to assign this macro to your checkbox of interest (right click on checkbox --> "assign macro"). 
The way you created checkboxes is interesting - it is either Form Control or AciveX Control. Please provide more information about it.

Comment: thanks Andrey, originally i didn't have double value.value.  the checkbox i'm executing this on is 21 so i thought the sub name had to match.  it is form control checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

i figured out how to do it with editing the cells, not the check boxes

```
Public Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If Range("AF3").Value = True Then
    Range("AA3").Value = True
    Range("AC3").Value = True
    Range("AE3").Value = True
    Range("AG3").Value = True
    Range("AD3").Value = True
    Range("AI3").Value = True
    Range("AH3").Value = True
    Range("AK3").Value = True
Else
    Range("AA3").Value = False
    Range("AC3").Value = False
    Range("AE3").Value = False
    Range("AG3").Value = False
    Range("AD3").Value = False
    Range("AI3").Value = False
    Range("AH3").Value = False
    Range("AK3").Value = False
End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

you can collapse your routine down to:

```
Public Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Range("AA3,AC3:AE3,AG3:AI3,AK3").Value = Range("AF3").Value
End Sub
```